# TYPO3 direct_mail_subscription Double-Opt-In-Out not activ

Tags: email, typo3, typoscript, newsletter

I am using extension direct_mail and direct_mail_subscription for newsletter. In the settings it is clear that i should first confirm the address, so the adress should be in the database as hidden.

```
// Create setup
create = 1
create {
    userFunc_afterSave = EXT:direct_mail_subscription/pi/class.dmailsubscribe.php:user_dmailsubscribe->saveRecord
    preview = 0
    // add captcha, if you use captcha
    fields = gender, name, hidden, email, module_sys_dmail_category, module_sys_dmail_html
    required = gender, name, email

    noSpecialLoginForm = 1
    # Initially hide the user until he approves!
    overrideValues.hidden = 1
    evalValues.email = uniqueLocal, email
}
```

so the field hidden in the database should be in the begining  1, however, all data are set to 0 without confirming the address.

Typo3 Version 8.7.2. What should the reason be?  Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have included the static TypoScript template in your own TypoScript template:

[image]

You can verify that it is included in the TypoScript Object Browser:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! the field "hidden" was missing in fields.
i had only first_name, last_name, email, module_sys_dmail_html.